# javascript function vs jquery namespace function, the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come a javascript function like this below...

```
function stars() {
var mOpacity = $('#area').css('opacity');
if (mOpacity = 1) {

$('#title').find('.stars').animate({"marginTop":"-170px",opacity:1}, 3000)
.animate({opacity: 0}, 400)
.animate({"marginTop":"60px",opacity:0},0, stars);
  }
}
stars();
```

...breaks my browser when I try to do something like this....

```
$.stars = function() {
var mOpacity = $('#area').css('opacity');
if (mOpacity = 1) {

$('#title').find('.stars').animate({"marginTop":"-170px",opacity:1}, 3000)
.animate({opacity: 0}, 400)
.animate({"marginTop":"60px",opacity:0},0, $.stars());
  }
}
$.stars();
```

What is the lesson here between the 2 styles of functions?

Thanks

**Ok based on everyones feedback to see more code, here is a full gimplse of the code on my .js file...**

```
function mIntro() {

/********PRE-GAME ANIMATION*********/
$('#area').css({'opacity':0}).delay(1000).animate({opacity:1},300);
$('#title').find('.age').css({'opacity':0}).delay(2000).animate({opacity:1}, 3000);

function stars() {
var mOpacity = $('#area').css('opacity');
if (mOpacity = 1) {

$('#title').find('.stars').animate({"marginTop":"-170px",opacity:1}, 3000)
.animate({opacity: 0}, 400)
.animate({"marginTop":"60px",opacity:0},0, stars);
  } 
}
stars();
}

$(function() {
  mIntro();
});
```

I have jquery connected to this .js page and I just can't understand why stars has to be in-cased in a traditional javascript function and not flexibile for a jquery namespace function.  I bet it has something to do with the animate tag that re-calls stars, but I am not sure...

Thanks or any advice!!!

Comment: Show us a demo at http://JSFiddle.net

Comment: It probably breaks because `$` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: Neither should break... but if you want to "namespace" jQuery like you do in the second example, you should use $.fn.stars. But I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Definitely true, especially if the OP is using `.noConflict()`...but they do say they are using jQuery at least...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inadvertently calling it in the second snippet:

```
.animate(..., $.stars());
```

You should code it the same way: pass the function, not the result of calling it:

```
Function:             stars      $.stars
Result of calling:    stars()    $.stars()
```

Comment: what do you mean?  I am using $.stars  = function(), with the $.stars() function name I passed in the animation script in my demo above...If this is the issue, please explain to me how to see my mistake...

Comment: @blachawk: As you can see, you passed `stars` rather than `stars()` in the first snippet. The same goes for `$.starts` instead of `$.starts()` - that's your mistake.

Comment: thank you for helping me understand - I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your first example is contained directly within the window object whereas the second example is contained in the jQuery ($) object (note that the $ object is then contained within the window object). As far as why it breaks when you attempt to use the jQuery namespace, I cant say without seeing all of your code, however $ is probably not defined.